# Merging cross-national panel databases in R

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning, economics

How do I merge cross-national databases, given 2 difficulties:

1. Not all databases have a country code variable
2. Some countries are listed with slightly different names (eg. Laos as Lao PDR, South Korea as Korea Rep.)

This is such a common task in social sciences yet I have not thought of an efficient way to do this other than manually matching country names.

Answer (score 1):

For extensive data sets or if merging problems appear frequently one powerful tool for merging data sets with slightly different names is [RecordLinkage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf).